# How Binding Class inside Class in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My problem is this, i have a class Match:

**Match.cs**

```
public class Match
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Team Team_1 { get; set; }
        public Team Team_2 { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Hour { get; set; }
        public string Local { get; set; }
        public string Statium { get; set; }
    }
```

and this class have Two objects `Team`, in Team i have this attributes:

**Team.cs**

```
 public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
...
```

im try Binding the Match object in my view:

```
 <ListBox Name="lbMatches" Height="480" >
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel Width="60" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Date}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hour}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Brazil" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Margin="20,0,10,0"/>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumb}"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="x" FontSize="32" Margin="10,0" Opacity="0.8"/>
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/team_image/thumbs/croacia.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Croatia" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Margin="10,0,20,0"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

But have a crucial duvid, how i make to acess the Name of Team Binding a Match ? bind the team of Match how make this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the relationship from `Match` to `Team` in a binding, e.g.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Team_1.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the ItemSource of your listbox. Next, you can access to Team attributes with : "Team_1.attribute"

Here an example :

xaml :

```
<ListBox Name="lbMatches" Height="480" ItemSource="{binding myMatch}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel Width="60" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Team_1.Name}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```